# Como listar los procesos en un servidor linux centos

Tags: linux, webservice, ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos

Hola tengo un servidor:

```
cat /etc/*release
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
```

y me pasa lo siguiente: la CPU generalmente está al 100% (Códigos de programación muy complejos)

Por ejemplo si quiero ver que procesos están consumiendo CPU utilizo un htop y me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que el htop me muestra solo unos cuantos procesos... yo los quiero saber todos asi como con el comando lsof o un ps -e

El otro problema es que los comandos (lsof o ps -e) no me muestran detalladamente el nombre del proceso como lo hace un htop (me muestra el nombre de los procesos que se ejecutan AutomateTraveler.calculate_options)

Pregunta: **Como hago para saber que procesos están corriendo en mi servidor?**

Comment: yo siempre lo miro con `ps -auxf`, así veo los hilos de cada  uno y bastante más información que con `ps e`... o bien uso `top` (más bien poco, solo en casos puntuales para saber cual es el que más consume)

Comment: que tal amigo, quizas esta web te sirva [https://openwebinars.net/blog/20-comandos-para-administrar-y-gestionar--facilmente-los-procesos-linux/], hay bastantes maneras de hacerlo la verdad, pero sugiero que proporciones mas detalles de lo que realmente quieres hacer. estas usando algun lenguaje en particular?

Comment: En htop puedes mover el cursor hacia abajo y vas viendo otros procesos.

Comment: @masterguru gracias por tu comentario... pero ps -auxf no me dice que método se está ejecutando.

Comment: @Alfabravo esa era la respuesta... con las flechas de dirección del teclado se pueden ver los procesos que existen más abajo.

Comment: @sysbot gracias por tu comentario... necesito mirar que métodos de ruby on rails consumen más CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad en htop es super poderoso... solo basta con pinchar en setup y eliminar las columnas que no necesitas... luego presionas en el teclado arriba o abajo y puedes ver los otros procesos... Así se hace el scroll en htop.